# Getting initializer in annotated field

Tags: java, annotations

Let's say I have this class:

`@Annotate class MyClass {
  MyField field = new MyField(params);
}`

How can I get the initializing part of my class field when I process my annotation (the `new MyField(params)` part)?

I can't see anything related in the `FieldDeclaration` class.

Comment: You want to access the source code (`.java`), given the compiled code (`.class`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Whether you use [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) or [apt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html), you cannot access code blocks.

- Through apt you can access anything you can annotate, but you can't annotate initializer blocks (although you could access an annotated local variable inside an initializer block).
- Through reflection there is no way to access code blocks (only Constructors, Fields, Methods and Classes)

If you are desperate enough about this, you need to use a source parser like [javaparser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) or a byte code tool like [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/). Both understand tree structures (the former uses source trees, the latter byte code trees) and can deal with all java structures, including initializer blocks.

But your best bet is probably [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) and it's `initialization(ConstructorSignature)` pointcut. There is some reference on [the pointcuts page](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html) but to really grasp it you would probably have to read [AspectJ in Action by Ramnivas Laddad](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/).