# Annotations on an initialization block???? static or not

Tags: java, annotations, initialization, block, scjp

I was just coding a Stripes action bean, starting with an annotated method.

By mistake i wrote:

```
@After(stages = LifecycleStage.ActionBeanResolution) {
    // code here
}
```

The compiler is OK

So it seems we can put annotations on static and nonstatic init blocks

```
@After(stages = LifecycleStage.ActionBeanResolution) 
{
    // code here
}

@After(stages = LifecycleStage.ActionBeanResolution) 
static {
    // code here
}
```

Do you have any usecase idea of such a strange thing?

Comment: Is it possible your compiler is not flagging this. A very well versed SO contributor suggests that you cannot annotate init blocks. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4691872/134894

Comment: You are right, it seems that my intellij IDE doesn't show me any error but with a maven compilation i have errors...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting initializer in annotated field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691577/getting-initializer-in-annotated-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it's a problem in my ide, it doesn't compile

Comment: Damn, that would have been very handy